# Android studio declaring Text size and Button sizes for different screen sizes

Tags: android

I made my first Android App. I read a lot about the images and made separate sizes for `mdpi` `hdpi` `xhdpi` and `xxhpi`.

Although i noticed i'm still having some issues on smaller screens `3.7"` and `4.0"` inches. What i noticed is that i'm using fixed values for things like `buttons` `TextViews` and `Text sizes`.

I came across and read about the `dimens` files but i'm still a little confused as to how should the folder structure should of the `values`.

To be more specific

`drawable`

`drawable-hdpi`

`drawable-mdpi`

`drawable-xhdpi`

`drawable-xxhdpi`

How is the `values` folder structure should be ?
I've read somewhere that it should look like `values-sw600dp`.
But what does the `600dp` represents ?
`600dpi` and up ??
Can i use custom values there or are there some fixed ones??

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after version 3.2 sw600dp is used for multi-layout panes for devices whose dp is greater than 600, where dp is :

```
px = dp * (dpi / 160)
```

This is irrelevant to your requirement (unless you want to make apps compatible for tablets).

Just make sure you put proportional image sizes in xhdpi,xxhdpi,mdpi and ldpi folders and use wrap_content for images. You can also use constant sizes, just make sure that you use dp for buttons and sp for text size.

Comment: I am using `sp` on all text but to give you an example, a string with a `17sp` size on a `hdpi` screen fills its width. Once i put that on an `xxhdpi` screen it's really small and not readable. I tried to make `values-mdpi` and so on folders to declare dimensions in there according to screen dpi but it won't recognize it

Comment: sp is like dp (or dip) but also takes into account user settings of font. maybe font size is set to small in your xxhdpi device?

Comment: You were right it was due to the devices font settings